# Sum the values of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}, {'Total Incidents': '1', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}]
```

I need to convert de value of 'Total Incidents' to int, and sum them up. Also, if the dates are equal, the function takes all the dates and turns them into one. For example, the output should be like this:

```
[{'Total Incidents': 9, 'CrimeDate':'05/14/2016'}]
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
dictf = reduce(lambda x, y: dict((k, v + y[k]) for k, v in x.iteritems()), dict1)
```

dict1 is a variable that contains the first dictionary.
But the ouput is not what I wanted, it gives me this :

```
{'Total Incidents': '111111111', 'CrimeDate': '05/14/201605/14/201605/14/201605/14/201605/14/201605/14/201605/14/201605/14/201605/14/2016'}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And if the dates aren't equal?

Comment: Let's say that there are two dates instead of one, the incidents are only summed if the dates that they occur are the same, so the output would have a list with two dictionaries instead of one.

Comment: And, what have you tried so far?

Comment: And ... have you tried anything yet?  We'll be happy to help you with a problem you've hit when attempting this yourself, but we're not a code-writing service.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've updated my question with my attempt.

Comment: See [ask]. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I just don't know how to convert the 'Total Incidents' into ints, and how to "concatenate" all the dates that are equal.

Comment: Maybe you should avoid reduce and lambda and try with simple for and if and what's the point of concatenating strings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> [{'CrimeDate': g[0], 'Total Incidents': sum(map(lambda x: int(x['Total Incidents']), g[1]))} for g in itertools.groupby(d, lambda x: x['CrimeDate'])]
[{'Total Incidents': 9, 'CrimeDate': '05/14/2016'}]
```

Comment: This is exacly what I need, Thank you. :)